# SharePoint 2010 RSS Viewer Web Part Accepting .XML File

Tags: 2010, web-part, xml, rss

I am trying to use the RSS Viewer web part on a team site and it accepts Feed URLs that end in .rss but when I insert one that ends in .xml, it doesn't load the content. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XML Viewer Web Part for this case(It can also display live rss feeds).

You can find it in the same place where you found the RSS feed web part.

It will give you the results which you need.

Kindly let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Regards,
Sukumar

Comment: Thank you for this. For some reason I get the message that says "Unable to retrieve the URL specified in the XML Link property" error message. Even though when i test my link - it opens up. The link is https://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/ContactFDA/StayInformed/RSSFeeds/MedWatch/rss.xml. What could the issue be?

Comment: Does the complete error says  "Unable to retrieve the URL specified in the XML Link property For more assistance, contact your site administrator "

If so then you have to enable anonymous access in central admin for getting the live feed. Let me know if you need help on this.